# Creating image file from Bitmapdata object

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been working to create an image file from Bitmapdata object using AS3.Can you place suggest an API that would help me achieve this.Following is the piece of snippet I am trying to use.

```
var imgByteData:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(scaleBitmapData(bitmapData, 0.70));
ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", scaleBitmapData(bitmapData, 0.70));
output.appendText("outside onload214312414\n");
file = new FileReference();
file.save(imgByteData, "image.jpg");
```

Regards,

Ankit

Comment: Drop `ExternalInterface` and `output` lines, should do. In fact, `JPGEncoder` and `FileReference` are the classes you need to save a JPG out of a `BitmapData`.

Comment: Also, you *might* need to trigger the `file.save()` via a key or mouse press because of security issues